# Why does the armature move when I move the lamp?

Tags: armature, lighting

When I move the recently added sun lamp it moves and distorts my model's armature.
I have not selected my model when I added the light so what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your armature is parented to the lamp.

Comment: or maybe because you've enabled the Proportional Editing option?